# Getting the URL of a node in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

**Goal**: To send an email with a list of URLs generated from nodes.

In my custom module I have managed to get the node id which the user wants and I now want to get the URL of each node to put into my email.

I searched the db and used google but I can't seem to find the right solution.

It seems we need to construct the URL something like this:

```
<?php
global $base_url;
$link=$base_url."// few more parameters
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x) function:

```
$options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
$nid = 1; // Node ID
$url = url('node/' . $nid, $options);
```

That will give you the absolute path (i.e. with http://example.com/ in front of it), with the URL aliased path to the node page.

Answer (score 15):

You can also try `drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$node->nid)`.

Comment: Is there some problem with this method? This seem more useful, and less obvious, than the approved answer.

Comment: What if the node has no alias? also, this will return a relative path.

Comment: Use in conjunction with $base_url global variable.

Comment: `drupal_lookup_path()` isn't always directly available, use `url()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can get it by

```
$path=drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$nid);
```

absolute path for nid

```
url('node/' . $node->id(), ["absolute" => TRUE]);
```

Comment: What if the node has no alias? also, this will return a relative path.

Comment: @cambraca yes it is return raw path  something like  `node/3`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function.

```
  l(t('Link text'), 'node/123', array('options' => array('absolute' => TRUE)));
```

Answer (score -5):

**use**

$node_url;

**it will give you the current node url**

Comment: You are not getting the question! please read the question carefully before answering